# Spark on K8s in Cluster mode: Is it possible to open additional ports?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, grpc

I have a Spark application running on Kubernetes that should open a gRPC service listening on Port 50051. By default, when running Spark jobs in cluster mode, Spark configures the pod to internally open ports 4040, 7078 and 7079.

Is it possible to configure, via `spark-defaults.conf`, additional ports to be opened or do I have to hand-craft a Pod/Service that runs the driver in client mode that opens the appropriate ports, as I am doing currently?